# Does Righteous Challenge stack with the effects of Divine Challenge/Sanction?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, mark

*"Righteous Challenge: Demons and Devils marked by your Divine Challenge/Sanction take a -2 penalty to all attack rolls"*

Divine Challenge/Sanction already impose a -2 attack penalty to attacks that don't target you. Would this feat mean that marked devils/demons suffer a -4 penalty to hit your allies (and not you) and a -2 to hit you?

Comment: Relevant: [Question about D&D 4E bonus stacking](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18981/12011)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, the penalties stack.**

1. Bonuses and penalties of the same type do not stack.
2. Untyped bonuses and penalties from the same source do not stack.

Divine Challenge/Sanction gives an untyped -2 penalty on attack rolls for attacks that do not include you. Righteous Challenge gives an untyped -2 penalty on attack rolls by targets marked by your DC/DS. Both bonuses are untyped, and are from a different sources (-2 from DC/DS, and -2 from RC).

Note that they stack explicitly because the feat applies a penalty to foes you marked with DC/DS; if it instead said that your DC/DS gives demons/devils -2 on all attacks then the feat would be changing how DC/DS work, rather than applying an additional penalty.